# Low Resolution While Using Fotoapparat

Tags: java, android, android-camera, mobile-application

I am testing Fotoapparat camera library for android and using v1 API. I took the sample project and ran it on several devices but apparently the camera resolution is very low compared to the native camera application. I use these lines while configuring the fotoapparat object:

```
.photoSize(standardRatio(biggestSize()))
.sensorSensitivity(highestSensorSensitivity())
```

I tried using:

```
.photoSize(highestResolution())
```

but it gives not resolved error. What am I doing wrong? Is the sample application wrong? Have anyone tried this and know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: what version of the library are you using? because I am also using the same and it works fine.

Comment: did you try setting `previewResolution`?

Comment: @karandeepsingh I use 1.5.0 the one in the sample. How can I learn the latest version?

Comment: try upgrading to 2.2.0.  https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat#set-up

Comment: @karandeepsingh now it doesn't recognize most of the imports and gives many errors

Comment: you should update your library and fix these errors as many bug fixes won't be there in old version.